# Identity Server and Active Driectory

Tags: active-directory, identityserver3

My current setup is a fairly simple one. I am running Identity Server 3 which is used to provide oauth access tokens which can be used against and a number of our web api endpoints. The identity server has custom user service which authenticates requests against a custom user table in our sql database.

We have a new 3rd party software provider, this provider requires that our users (staff in our call centre) logon to their application via a proprietary login, not against our existing user accounts. We have built an api for this 3rd party which they required for their integration, as with the rest of our api's this is secured using oauth bearer tokens via identity server.

Our staff are all locally logged on to an active directory domain. Is it possible to configure identity server to issues auth tokens for a user who is already authenticated against active directory? I like to achieve this without prompting the user for their credentials again.

I've read around and at this point I'm very lost as to the correct approach, some form of federation seems appropriate, but I couldn’t find a reasonable introduction / walkthrough to help me get started.

What is an appropriate approach and are they any relatively easy to consume primers on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to make it work. The [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source) contain a windows auth provider. Using this, your identity server would authenticate people in without prompting for a password. Once authenticated, it would then issue tokens same as any other auth. You may need to a bit of experimenting to get it working, but from what you've said it should work in your situation.